# Facebook Comments: Hide All Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Using the Facebook Comments plugin and there's a setting called data-num-posts, which must be a minimum of 1. However, there is no current way to not show any comments. The idea is to allow the user to comment using the comment box. The comments would then be retrieved via the Graph API.

Is this currently possible by way of any settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, the Facebook comments plugin does not currently offer this ability.